# Creating a liquid formatted site for larger browsers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website that will be able to change as the browser size change.

I have created a very simple setup of what i have so far http://jsfiddle.net/QH567/3/

The red is my main content area it always has to be over that specific portion of the image.

Now the thing is i want that image to align vertically depending on how large the browser is and i want to fill the top section as it grows with a gradient. Is this possible? i have it now where it reveals the image as the browser gets bigger horizontally but i also want to do it vertically and instead of revealing more image i want to just add a gradient. I think i need more divs more wrappers more something i am just lost!

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
    <p id="subhead"><strong>Select your grade below,</strong> see the college success steps
        <br/>you need to complete, and discover great apps!</p>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="applist.html">App List</a>

            </li>
            <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<!-- Main Container -->
<div id="mainContent"></div>
</div>
<!-- END OF WRAPPER -->
<footer></footer>
```

The CSS is in jsfiddle.

Comment: Also for some odd reason i cannot click on the nav either. But when i do put a height on the <ul> and it shifts my mainContent div down ruining my flow

Comment: Well you can use 'background-size: cover;' in your css to display full image across all browsers.

Comment: That's not what i'm trying to accomplish i really just have to center that wrapper vertically and probably just give the background a gradient image so it can do its thing